# Deserialize json array in Dart/Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

How to deserialize this json array `[{"i":737,"n":1}]` to get the variable "i" e "n".

Class to deserialize

```
    class PortasAbertas {
  int i;
  int n;

  PortasAbertas({this.i, this.n});

  PortasAbertas.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    i = json['i'];
    n = json['n'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'i': i,
      'n': n
    };
  }
}
```

I'm trying deserialize the object using this code, but use it when dont have a array, but using array i don't know i can do it

```
   PortasAbertas objeto = new PortasAbertas.fromJson(responseJson);
     String _msg = ("Portas abertas: ${objeto.n}");
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
final List t = json.decode(response.body);
final List<PortasAbertas> portasAbertasList =
     t.map((item) => PortasAbertas.fromJson(item)).toList();
return portasAbertasList;
```

You can parse your JSON to list like that so you can use fromJson in an array.

Comment: what if all the json comes back as the same name e.g. `[
    {
        "store": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
        "store": "FLIPKART"
    },
    {
        "store": "WALMART"
    },
    {
        "store": "ALIBABA"
    },

]`

Comment: where does the method fromJson come from in PortasAbertas?

Answer (score 5):

You can try using this lines,

```
List oo = jsonDecode('[{"i":737,"n":1},{"i":222,"n":111}]');
//here u get the values from the first value on the json array
print(oo[0]["i"]);
print(oo[0]["n"]);

//here u get the values from the second value on the json array
print(oo[1]["i"]);
print(oo[1]["n"]);
```

and for each value from your list, u have a json and can get access the value using "i" or "n";

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but I solved using below code.

```
List jsonResult = jsonDecode(await RequestApiCallDemo().loadAsset());
for (var value in jsonResult) {
      ItemCategoryModel itemCategoryModel = ItemCategoryModel.fromJson(value);
      print("itemCategoryModel Item = " + itemCategoryModel.title);
}
```

If we convert json to dart we will only get Model that support Json-Object so the better approach is to do jsonDecode first and then insert object to your model

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a `List<dynamic>` and map that list to `fromJson` of the model you expect.

```dart
final decoded = jsonDecode(json) as List<dynamic>;
final output = decoded
    .map((e) => ItemCategoryModel.fromJson(
        e as Map<String, dynamic>))
    .toList();
```